# How to sideload language packs MSIX inside MSIXbundle?

Tags: windows-store-app, windows-11, windows-store

I'm using Windows Subsystem for Android on my Windows 11 22000.318 PC. In order to root and use Google apps inside WSA, I had to sideload the app by directly extracting the saPackage_1.8.32822.0_x64_Release-Nightly.MSIX archive and registring its AppManifest.xml.

Without the supplementary language packs in the MSIX bundle, the WSA app will be installed in English only. I tried editing "Resources→Language" entry in AppsManifest.xml but it didn't change the language, I've also tried installing the language MSIX archive but will get the error message that the app is already installed.

Comment: It's not possible to run `Windows Subsystem for Android` on Windows 11 22000.318.  How did you achieve that exactly? It's only possible to run WSA on the current Beta Insider Preview build.  Are you sure you are running 22000?

Comment: You can just download and install the MSIXbundle directly. Although not shown in Microsoft Store, WSA app is actually compatible with 22000 build. The same goes for WSL Microsoft Store Preview.

Comment: It certainly based on everything released about WSA isn’t supposed to work. However, the answer to your question, is probably going to be “not possible” due to the way you installed it